# LilyPond - start measure on second volta if first volta measure is not complete

Tags: lilypond, repeats

I am trying to transcribe a Bach manuscript from BWV 1004.

Bar 9 of the Sarabande has what looks like a Segno. Then in measure 25 we need to jump back to this segno. I have this for measures 24-26:

```
\relative c'' {  
    \key f \major
    \time 3/4

    % 24
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "1"))
    d8. c!16( bes a g f e d cis d32 e)
    
    % 25
    <<
        {
            e'8. f32( g) -\markup {
                \italic "D.S. "
                \tiny \raise #1
                \musicglyph "scripts.segno"
            }
        }
        \\
        { < cis, a a, >4 }
    >>

    % 26
    % 6th pentagram from Bach's manuscript starts on 2nd beat
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "2") end-repeat)
    d16 d, f a g( f e d c bes) c( a)

}
```

It works like a charm, the only problem is that measure 26 is considering what was written in measure 25 and so it is being cut short by a 4th (just like the `end-repeat` bar not be there). Is there a way in which I could add hidden rests **that do not take up any space**? Because if I add `s`s, it works, bars come back to be written correctly but the hidden rests widen measure 25 in a noticeable/unpleasant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using a *partial measure*, specified by \partial duration. So in your case you need \partial 4 like here:

```
\relative c'' {   
    \time 3/4
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "1"))
    d8. c!16( bes a g f e d cis d32 e)
    
    % 25
    \partial 4
    <<
        {
            e'8. f32( g) -\markup {
                \italic "D.S. "
                \tiny \raise #1
                \musicglyph "scripts.segno"
            }
        }
        \\
        { < cis, a a, >4 }
    >>
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta "2") end-repeat)
    d16 d, f a g( f e d c bes) c( a)
    \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix to fool the time-keeping algorithm is usually to make the last note *look* like one length but *count as* another. Lilypond calls this "Scaling durations" (see the [documentation on this](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms)), and the syntax looks like this: `d4*2`. It renders a quarter note that counts as a half note.

Comment: The problem is that this will still affect scaling. The correct way to achieve this is using partial measures with \partial.

Comment: You're right, didn't notice that OP had an upbeat in the sample.